# Search functions on an RTF Editor

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm creating an RTF Editor and I need help with the search functions.  I have already created the find and replace code but I cant figure out how to code the `find next` and `replace all` code.  Any help will be much appreciated. The following is the code that I have already. ( I am using Visual studio 2010 c# )

```
    private void buttonFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        RichTextBox frm1TB = ((Form1)this.Owner).rTB;

        int foundAt;
        foundAt = frm1TB.Text.IndexOf(txtSearch.Text);
        if (foundAt == -1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not Found");
        }
        else
        {

            frm1TB.SelectionStart = foundAt;
            frm1TB.SelectionLength = txtSearch.TextLength;
            frm1TB.Focus();
            btnFindnext.Enabled = true;
            btnReplaceall.Enabled = true;
            btnReplace.Enabled = true;

        }

    }

    private void buttonfindNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void buttonreplace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RichTextBox frm1TB = ((Form1)this.Owner).rTB;
        btnFind_Click(sender,e);

        frm1TB.SelectedText = txtReplace.Text;         


        }

    private void buttonreplaceAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but StackOverflow doesn't have monkeys to write the code for you.

Comment: I was only asking for help mate, i didnt ask you to write the program for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just to this:

```
frm1TB.Rtf = frm1TB.Rtf.Replace("replace what", "with this");
```

Comment: cheers for that ,quite annoying that it took one line of code to sort the replace all and ive been at it for days . Cheers mate

Answer (score 2):

you can use the this [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xkyx09y.aspx) of indexOf, define the startIndex as the index of the last result you've found + the length of the search string. now the indexOf will give you the location of the string in txtSearch.Text in the RTF box **after** the last occurrence.

to replace all just [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx)